# Application design: how much Redux state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am currently working on building a small-ish app (6 front-end container-style components, 15 backend DB tables), in React.

I'm playing around with importing Redux, and I'm having a hard time designing my application state. It seems that I'll need to store broad-based state (e.g. user sessions) into Redux, but most of the other state I'll be pulling from the backend and won't necessarily *need* it to be always up-to-date 100%.

Based on all of the "redux-todo" style examples out there, it would seem that folks would store *everything* in their Redux store (since the state is relatively small, I suppose).

However, for my case, I'm wondering if Redux should just be a super lightweight store for only that which needs to be persisted across the app, a la an Ember-style 'service'.

Am I thinking about this correctly? Or should I be looking to store more state inside Redux?

Comment: Store what ever state your front-end needs in order to render the UI and nothing more.

Comment: What is this other kind of state that doesn't seem to matter so much? Can you give some examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've struggled with that exact issue.  It really takes some getting used to, but as another answer said, *if* you're using Redux, the idiomatic approach is to store basically everything in the Redux store. The one exception (and these turn out to be rather rare) is UI-only data such as a visibility toggle or dropdown info that sets a class or the like.  That is, data that is ephemeral and has no impact on anything outside the component in which it lives. Even then, you will find that some UI-only items are easier to manage using actions and reducers as they often end up touching other items.

Edited to add: as the comment below states, the official Redux docs don't take a position on this issue. Which is one reason why so many people struggle with these issues -- you have a ton of freedom how to structure your React/Redux apps.  My advice should be understood to be advice based on the experience of trying different approaches.  Here are the three main reasons that I've seen for putting state into store:

1. more often than not, something I put into state ended up being needed somewhere else and getting it there through props required more work than if I had just put the data in the Redux store to start with.
2. Additionally, it's common to refactor your app to split apart components into more modular reusable pieces as your app grows and gets more complex. If you have data in state that is used in two places in a component you then won't be able split that component into smaller pieces easily.
3. Finally, readability.  It's nice to be able to glance at your mapStateToProps call and see exactly what props are received or used by each component.

The problem is that Redux and putting everything in the store can feel like a lot of unneeded complexity when the actions and impact of the items is simple. If that's the case, I would suggest you consider dropping Redux at least at first. It will be a lot of work to refactor, but it will help you appreciate just where Redux shines.  On the other hand, you may in fact not really need it for your app.

Back to your original question, yes, *in my opinion*, you should be putting more in the Redux store. Everything goes in there with a few very narrow exceptions. Data from the backend in particular should go into the store as a first step before getting mapped to props in the components where it's used.

Comment: "The problem is that Redux and putting everything in the store can feel like a lot of unneeded complexity when the actions and impact of the items is simple." Yes, yes, yes. This is exactly what it feels like. Alrighty, then - this makes sense. Guess I'll soldier on. Thanks!

Comment: Per the Redux FAQ at http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-only-redux-state , **it's up to you as the developer to decide where your state lives**.  It may make sense to put something into Redux, or it may be easier to keep it in local component state.  YOU should make that decision based on your own needs.

Comment: @markerikson Yes, I've expanded my answer to make clear that this is personal experience based advice, not an issue with a documented correct or incorrect answer. Abramov and the React/Redux teams go out of their way to avoid dictating how their tools are used.  That's part of what makes the library so incredibly liberating, but also adds to the challenge of using the tools to their fullest potential.  Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to store any state your app needs to function. Your React components don't know anything about data other than what to do with it once they have it. The React/Redux "way" is that the *only* way they get it is from your Redux store.

So if you're fetching a list of items on app load, that goes in your store. Then your app has it for the entirety of the session. If someone leaves and comes back, or reloads the page, it fetches again, and stores a fresh copy in Redux again. You may not create any actions to modify it once it's there, and you may not need to fetch it again any time soon, but that's where it should live so your components can get stuff from it.

If you didn't store it in Redux where would you put it? And how would your components gain access to it?

Comment: `If you didn't store it in Redux where would you put it? And how would your components gain access to it?`
... So here's what I'm thinking: if I'm rendering a list of tweets, say, in `<TweetList />` - I wouldn't have to store all the tweets (and all the users, etc.) in the Redux store - I could just throw a fetch('api/tweets') in the `componentDidMount` hook of the TweetList component.

Comment: That my work for something pretty simple, but you may find that at some point you maybe want to put a badge in the `Header` denoting how many tweets the user has. And since the `Header` is way over on the other side of your app, how do you get that information to it? You might start going down some dark roads trying to get components to communicate with each other.